# Can files be iterated over, exactly as they are stored / shown in the file system?

Tags: python, os.walk

I have several folders in one root folder, each of which contains files and I know that the first two files are always the relevant files. But when I iterate over the folders, the files are no longer in the order they were in the file system. Sorting the files is also a problem, as they are not alphanumerically in the file system.

Is there a way to iterate over the files, exactly as they are stored / shown in the file system (I use a Mac)?

How it looks in the file system:

[image]

[image]

What I tried:

```
import os

path = "root_dir"
for _, _, files in os.walk(path):
    files.sort()
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

What it printed:

```
000000000ac200.xml
000000000ac200_D_015.jpg
000000000ac200_D_016.jpg
000000000ac200_S_001.pdf
000000000ac200_S_002.pdf
000000000ac200__001.jpg
000000000ac200__002.jpg
'######
10002281.jpg
10_561593833.jpg
11_658704958.jpg
4_638893120.jpg
6_554989888.jpg
7_701137820.jpg
'######
```

Comment: `first two files`: what is your filesystem's sort filter.

Comment: Sort filter is by name - according to the setting in the system.

Comment: what does this mean : as they are not alphanumerically in the file system?

Comment: *You* need to figure out which part of the filename is causing the files in question to be listed first, and sort the files using an appropriate key, or use some more reliable method than *"the first two files"* to select them. A regex that natches `__001.jpg` & `__002.jpg` is trivial, for example

Comment: There is no real "order" to the files. You can choose in what order they are *displayed*

Comment: Do the first two files always follow a similar pattern? Or are the names of the first two files in different folders very different?